# Why is my time filter not updating within my Quasar template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, filter, quasar

I've created a vue project for my assignment, and I want to show a formatted time on a section of the webpage. However, even after passing it through a filter, I'm still seeing the same unformatted epoch time.

I want to show the time on my webpage in a certain format, and therefore I've used a filter as such:

```
filters: {
    niceDate(timeStamp) {
      const dateObject = new Date(timeStamp * 1000);
      const formattedDate = date.formatDate(dateObject, "MMMM D h:mm A");
      return formattedDate;
    },
  },
```

I've also referenced this in the template like this:
`<div class="text-caption text-grey">{{ post.date | niceDate }}</div>`

Note that both the filter and template are from the same file (a Page file)

However, the result I see is still the epoch value from my object being shown instead of the formatted time:

```
{
          id: 1,
          user: "Tucker",
          emotion: "happy",
          location: "Mirihana, Sri Lanka",
          date: 1710799030927, // This is what I see on the browser, but I want it to be formatted
          caption: "I like biting people",
          imgURL: "https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/parallax2.jpg",
        },
```

EDIT: `formatDate()` is a utility function from Quasar FYI

Comment: `date` in the expression `date.formatDate()` is not defined in your code.  where does it come from?

Comment: also if you console log `new Date(timeStamp * 1000)` with your timestamp value you get a date in the year 56183.  Multiplying by 1000 is probably a mistake.

Comment: @yoduh the formatDate() function is a utility function in Quasar. Here's a ref https://quasar.dev/quasar-utils/date-utils#validate 
Noted on the * 1000 xD

Comment: I see.  Is this Vue 3 then?  If so, [filters are deprecated](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html#_3-x-update).  You can replace the filter with a method or computed property instead.